# How do I fix Illegal parameter in definition

Tags: macros, texstudio

This small bit of code in my larger document isn't working

```
\def\saliva#1#2{%
\makebox[\textwidth]{\mbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{
\event{#1}{$\hbar$}{Collect saliva  \underline{in sleep laboratory suite}} \newline
Obtain the Salivette for \textbf{\underline{saliva sample \##2}} for each subject \newline
Also collect a cotton swab for each subject \newline
\underline{Verify that you have the correct tubes!} {\textbf{This is saliva sample \##2}} \newline
Refer to saliva collection procedures posted on the board in sleep lab kitchenette \newline
Have participants place swab \textbf{under the tongue} and collect saliva for \textbf{2 minutes} \newline
At the end of 2 minutes, ask each subject if the cotton swab feels saturated \newline
If the swab is \textbf{not saturated}, collected saliva for an additional minute and note in protocol \newline
Quickly take the Salivettes to the exam room and give to the trained RA for processing}}}}
```

It gives the following error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \saliva#1#2
```

The code is tested and works fine otherwise. Can someone help please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is `\event` defined?

Comment: The above code produces no error if added to a latex document please always provide a small complete document that shows any error that you are asking about.

Comment: Guesswork: Seems this is a snippet copied from a .tex-file containing more code. Make sure that in the original each opening-brace `{` has a matching closing-brace `}` in the right place. If, e.g., due to a typo during editing, the closing-brace of a `\def`inition-text is lost, TeX "thinks" that things belong to the definition-text which are not intended to belong to it. If these things contain `#3` or`#4` or whatsoever parameters not listed in the `\def`inition's parameter text, you get error-messages like `Illegal parameter number in definition of \saliva#1#2` `<to be read again>`  `3`.

Comment: The other way round: The error-message `Illegal parameter number in definition of ...` often indicates a problem with the matching of closing-braces  `}` of definition-texts.